# How to show all logs including the merged branches in git-flow

Tags: git, git-merge, git-flow, git-log

I took `git-flow` to do my work,

But I wonder how to see the merged-branch logs after I merged the branch.

for example, when I finished the branch `feature/support_vadp`

I can no see the logs in that branch anymore.

```
584c054 - (HEAD, hotfix/fix_duplicated_partial_only_items) Ignore: experimental seeding files (24 minutes ago) <poc7667>
bbaffaf - (master) Merge branch 'develop' (31 minutes ago) <poc7667>
7bc6c17 - (develop) Merge branch 'feature/support_vadp' into develop (37 minutes ago) <poc7667>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That would be the log of the develop branch, where you merged your feature branch.
To see all branches:

```
git log --all --branches
```

It also depends on how you are using git-flow: [with SourceTree](http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/08/01/smart-branching-with-sourcetree-and-git-flow/) for instance, you would have the option to finish and delete the branch:

[image: http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/files/2012/07/flow_finishfeature.png]

(in which case you wouldn't be able to see the feature branch commit, even with a `git log --all --branches`)

See more at "[Finishing a feature branch with GIT Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16403826/6309)".